# How do I make a image viewer?

Tags: javascript, image

I want to make an image viewer (for my website) like the one in Facebook (the old one). When the user click the next or back arrow it will change the picture and the URL of the page.

This is an example of what I want (http://www.facebook.com/pages/Forest-Ville/307556775942281)

Most importantly I want the page to reload with each click with new (URL, comment box, ads, etc.) I do not want to use any Cookies. Now I am using this, but its completely different from what I want.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<script language="JavaScript">

            var NumberOfImages = 10
            var img = new Array(NumberOfImages)

            img[0] = "http://damnthisfunny.site40.net/1.jpg"
            img[1] = "http://damnthisfunny.site40.net/2.jpg"
            img[2] = "http://damnthisfunny.site40.net/3.jpg"
            img[3] = "http://damnthisfunny.site40.net/4.jpg"
            img[4] = "http://damnthisfunny.site40.net/5.jpg"
            img[5] = "http://damnthisfunny.site40.net/6.jpg"
            img[6] = "http://damnthisfunny.site40.net/7.jpg"
            img[7] = "http://damnthisfunny.site40.net/8.jpg"
            img[8] = "http://damnthisfunny.site40.net/9.jpg"
            img[9] = "http://damnthisfunny.site40.net/10.jpg"

            var imgNumber = 0
            function NextImage()
            {
                imgNumber++
                if (imgNumber == NumberOfImages)
                    imgNumber = 0
                document.images["VCRImage"].src = img[imgNumber]
            }
            function PreviousImage()
            {
                imgNumber--
                if (imgNumber < 0)
                    imgNumber = NumberOfImages - 1
                document.images["VCRImage"].src = img[imgNumber]
            }


</script>



<body>
<center>

<img name="VCRImage" src="http://damnthisfunny.site40.net/1.jpg" /></dr>
<br />
<a href="javascript:PreviousImage()">
<img border="0" src="left1.jpg" /></a>
<a href="javascript:NextImage()">
<img border="0" src="right1.jpg" /></a>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to reload the page every time, you can simply update `location.href` and append it with a hash value denoting the image you want to load:

```
<img id="theImg" name="VCRImage" src="http://damnthisfunny.site40.net/1.jpg" /></dr>
<a href="javascript:PreviousImage()">
<img border="0" src="left1.jpg" /></a>
<a href="javascript:NextImage()">
<img border="0" src="right1.jpg" /></a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var NumberOfImages = 10
    var img = new Array(NumberOfImages);
    img[0] = "http://damnthisfunny.site40.net/1.jpg";
    img[1] = "http://damnthisfunny.site40.net/2.jpg";
    img[2] = "http://damnthisfunny.site40.net/3.jpg";
    img[3] = "http://damnthisfunny.site40.net/4.jpg";
    img[4] = "http://damnthisfunny.site40.net/5.jpg";
    img[5] = "http://damnthisfunny.site40.net/6.jpg";
    img[6] = "http://damnthisfunny.site40.net/7.jpg";
    img[7] = "http://damnthisfunny.site40.net/8.jpg";
    img[8] = "http://damnthisfunny.site40.net/9.jpg";
    img[9] = "http://damnthisfunny.site40.net/10.jpg";

    var imgNum = parseInt(location.hash.substring(location.hash.indexOf('img=')+4));
    if (isNaN(imgNum) || imgNum < 1 || imgNum > NumberOfImages)
        imgNum = 1;
    document.getElementById('theImg').src = img[imgNum];

    function NextImage()
    {
        location.href = 'this.html#img='+(imgNum+1);
    }
    function PreviousImage()
    {
        location.href = 'this.html#img='+(imgNum-1);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: but the problem now is every time I reload the page it will rest the slidshow to the first image.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) plugin for a project like this, and then customizing it to suite your needs.

Here is a link to get you stared : http://www.designsmag.com/2011/06/50-jquery-image-gallery-tutorials-and-plugins/

Answer (score -1):

sRGB IEC61966-2.1ISO Coated v2 (ECI)Dot Gain

15%CmykRelativeColorimetricfalsetrue<HasGra

yscaleObjects>false

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).